# Dataset XML serialization to memory stream

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have a strongly typed DataSet and a corresponding class generated with xsd.exe.

I wanted to pass DataSet content to the matching class with XML serialization/deserialization.

If I use something like:

```
MyStronglyTypedDataSet ds = new MyStronglyTypedDataSet();
//... fill the dataset...
ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Temp\somedata.xml");

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\somedata.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDataSetMatchingClass));
MyDataSetMatchingClass myObj = (MyDataSetMatchingClass)serial.Deserialize(fs);
```

Everything works fine, but I don't want to use a temporary file so I tried:

```
MyStronglyTypedDataSet ds = new MyStronglyTypedDataSet();
//... fill the dataset...
MemoryStream dump = new MemoryStream();
ds.WriteXml(dump);

XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDataSetMatchingClass));
MyDataSetMatchingClass myObj = (MyDataSetMatchingClass)serial.Deserialize(dump);
```

But the deserializer complains that root XML node is missing. Anyone knows a way to tell the XmlWriter to append the root node, or the deserializer to ignore missing root node or any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't rewind the stream. This is a very common problem (see [How many ways can you mess up IO?](http://marcgravell.blogspot.ie/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html) - look for "Gotchas when buffering data in memory"). Set:

```
dump.Position = 0;
```

between the write (serialize) and the read (deserialize).